# Uploading Photos without album-id using facebook-graph-api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

When I use the facebook Graph API to upload a photo it seems as if I have to specify which photo album to upload to.  When using the old graph api, if I didn't specify an album, an album specify to my application would be created on the user's behalf and the photo would upload to there.  (ie. 'Super App Photos').

Can I get this same behavior (a new album for my app being created without specifying an album_id) with the Graph API?  Or, alternatively can I use the rest-apit to upload a photo after authenticating through the graph-api's oauth2.0 flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph API has the same behavior. They create the album named after the app.

Comment: You are correct. the trick is to post to graph.facebook.com/[profileid]/photos.  Not sure how I missed it the first time around.